# JQuery scroll listbox imitation with keyboard navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox

My javascript listbox implementation:

```
$(function() {
    $('#listbox1').on('keydown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var $e = $(this).find('.selected');
        switch(e.which) {
            case 38:
                ($e.prev().length) && ($e = $e.removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected'));
                $(this).scrollTop( $e.position().top + $(this).scrollTop() );
            break;
            case 40:
                ($e.next().length) && ($e = $e.removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected'));
                $(this).scrollTop( $e.position().top + $(this).scrollTop() );
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qy8p2x1/.

There are presented a real listbox and his imitation. I do not go so they scrolled the same **using keyboard navigation arrows (up & down)**. A real listbox is not scrolling until it reaches the last element but imitation does so (following each element). ScrollUp is working properly.

Please, help me implement scrollDown behaviour correctly.

Comment: So, you want to move the Real listbox options immediately when you move to next element?

Comment: I made function like that year ago, i can show u, if u have time for looking. https://cloudbg.ru/users   login: f1553233@trbvm.com password: f1553233@trbvm.com
 on https://cloudbg.ru/users click on the left select input and just downarrow or up arrow. if u like it - i gave u code.

Comment: @Legendary, its ok. Is that i looking up.

Answer (score 1):

i use .jspPane for scrolling list, but u can it without jsp (if u ok with coffe) can show to you .coffee - it more readable. If u have question - ill help u

```
var keyboard_control, scroll_to_active;

keyboard_control = function() {
  $('.control-edu').on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
    var $active, $first, $last, $this, i, temp;
    $this = $(this);
    $active = $('.jspPane span.active');
    $first = $('.jspPane span.opinion').first();
    $last = $('.jspPane span.opinion').last();
    if ($this.closest('.control-edu').find('.options span').length > 1) {
      if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        if ($active.length > 0) {
          if ($active.prev().length > 0) {
            temp = $active.prev();
            $active.removeClass('active');
            temp.addClass('active');
          } else {
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $last.addClass('active');
          }
        } else {
          $last.addClass('active');
        }
        i = $('.jspPane span.active').closest('.control-edu').index();
        scroll_to_active(i, 0);
      } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        if ($active.length > 0) {
          if ($active.next().length > 0) {
            temp = $active.next();
            $active.removeClass('active');
            temp.addClass('active');
          } else {
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $first.addClass('active');
          }
        } else {
          $first.addClass('active');
        }
        i = $('.jspPane span.active').closest('.control-edu').index();
        scroll_to_active(i, 1);
      } else if (e.keyCode === 13 && $active.length > 0) {
        $active.click();
      }
    }
  });
};

scroll_to_active = function(i, flag) {
  var $active;
  $active = $('.jspPane span.active');
  if (flag === 1) {
    if (($active.next().length > 0) && ($active.prev().length > 0)) {
      api[i - 1].scrollToElement($active.next());
    } else if ($active.prev().length === 0) {
      api[i - 1].scrollToElement($active);
    } else if ($active.next().length === 0) {
      api[i - 1].scrollToBottom();
    }
  } else if (flag === 0) {
    if ($active.next().length > 0) {
      api[i - 1].scrollToElement($active);
    } else {
      api[i - 1].scrollToBottom();
    }
  } else {
    return

  }
};
```

Edited: remove js2coffee return

Comment: `scrollToBottom` . Where is scroll implementation?

Comment: my mistake, it from jspPane, http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js . I try to find it func and rewrite

Comment: I checked - it implement from .jspPane, and it cannot be simpel to rewrite, if u dont want use .jspPane - i remove my ans, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/7qy8p2x1/1/

```
$(function() {
$('#listbox1').on('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var $e = $(this).find('.selected');
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38:
            ($e.prev().length) && ($e = $e.removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected'));
            $(this).scrollTop( $e.position().top + $(this).scrollTop() );
        break;
        case 40:
            ($e.next().length) && ($e = $e.removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected'));
            $(this).scrollTop( $e.position().top + $(this).scrollTop() );
        break;
    }
});

$('#listbox2').on('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var $e = $(this).find(':selected');
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38:
            ($e.prev().length) && ($e = $e.removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected'));
            $(this).scrollTop( $e.position().top + $(this).scrollTop() );
        break;
        case 40:
            ($e.next().length) && ($e = $e.removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected'));
            $(this).scrollTop( $e.position().top + $(this).scrollTop() );
        break;
    }
});  });
```

Comment: Have you checked the jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
$(function() {
    $('#listbox1').on('keydown', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var $e = $(this).find('.selected');
        switch(e.which) {
            case 38:
                ($e.prev().length) && ($e = $e.removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected'));
                ($e.position().top < 0) && ($(this).scrollTop( $e[0].offsetTop ));
            break;
            case 40:
                ($e.next().length) && ($e = $e.removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected'));
                ($e.position().top - $(this).height() + $e.height() > 0) && ($(this).scrollTop( $e[0].offsetTop - $(this).height() + $e.outerHeight() ));
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7qy8p2x1/7/

Cross-browser (but workaround) solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/7qy8p2x1/4/